# Inserting means between 2 numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $A_1, A_2, A_3... A_{2012}$ and $H_1, H_2, H_3 ... H_{2012}$ be arithmetic and harmonic means between $a$ and $b$ respectively. If $A_{1006}H_{1007}$ = 2013 then what is:
>   $$\frac{A_5H_{2008}}{A_{10}H_{2003}}$$

---

I don't know how to go about this problem.
I tried doing this:

$$A_{1006} = a + 1006\bigg(\frac{b-a}{2013}\bigg)$$
$$\frac{1}{H_{1007}} = \frac{1}{a}+ 1007\big(\frac{\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a}}{2013}\big)$$

and then equating the product to 2013, but that doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

---

The solution in my book simply states that $A_5H_{2008} = A_{10}H_{2003}$, that's why the answer is 1, but I don't get it. Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your book ***could*** be assuming that
$$
A_n H_{2013-n}=2013
$$
or equivalently
$$
H_n=\frac{2013}{A_{2013-n}}=\frac{2013}{b-n\cdot d}
$$
where $d=\dfrac{b-a}{2013}$. If so then surely $A_5 H_{2008}=A_{10} H_{2003}=2013$.

But then we have $H_0=\dfrac{2013}{b}$ and $H_{2013}=\dfrac{2013}{a}$ which seems rather strange. Which definition of harmonic mean does your book give? Is it clear what is meant?

Comment: How, though? I don't recall reading anywhere that $A_rH_{(n+1)−r}=(n+1)$ in cases like these.